# graphics.py and zelle - is there a sound module with graphics.py? If not, how about tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, audio, zelle-graphics

Is there a sound/audio module with graphics.py (zelle) that lets you play mp3 or wav files within python?

If there is not, is there a way of doing the same with Tkinter?  I have used OS to open mp3, but it use VLC player, I would prefer it to natively open with the underlying code of graphics.py or tkinter... Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by `graphics.py` but I can tell you that `tkinter` doesn't have support for any video/sound file format (except `.gif`). You can use `pygame` to run the sound file in the background.

Comment: it is a python module created by John Zelle.  It does graphics, but I was hoping there might be something in there for audio too.
https://knowledge.kitchen/John_Zelle_Python_Graphics_Module

Comment: No and no, there isn't.

Comment: @netrate I looked over `graphics.py` and it looks like it's built on top of `tkinter`. As it's built on top of `tkinter`, there is no way it can support sound. I would say that it should only be used for teaching. Also I dislike how they just tried to ignore event driven programming, which means that people who use it might get very confused when go to a real GUI library.

Comment: Why do you need to play mp3 or wav files in tkinter? Do you want to create an audio player or play certain (e.g., system) sounds on certain application events?

Comment: I was just hoping to use sounds with graphics.py - have them play in the background, when buttons are pressed etc.

Comment: If you want to do graphics and sound — note I didn't say a GUI and sounds — I suggest you consider `pygame`. If you look around you may be able to find a GUI based on it instead of `tkinter`. There's also something called [`wxPython`](https://www.wxpython.org/), but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: I am going to use winsound for it. That seems to be the easiest way forward.